# Product - how to refer the action for standard button "Save & Add Price"

Tags: visualforce

I had created a new VF page as like the page for editing the products which seems to work fine. I have a button 'Save' and 'Cancel' for which i have the action for the buttons as action="{!save}" and action="{!cancel}". though i do not have any codes at the controller for save and cancel the page is pretty much doing its job. so the question is:

1. does the action for save and cancel i have as below are standard actions for save and cancel?

   ```
       <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
       <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
   ```
2. in standard When creating a new product i see another button 'Save & Add price' which takes me to a subsequent screen to add the price. How can i get the action for 'Save & Add price' button so that i can use it in my controller in way from my custom VF page I can do the add price page directly?

Comment: If you've written a controller Extension, `{!save}` will invoke the extension class's `save()` method, if present, else the standard Controller's `save()` method. If you've written a custom controller, then you have to have a `save()` (and for that matter, `cancel()` custom method implemented. More info is needed here and for #2 you should show what you tried

Comment: Thkx Crop, it helped